# Changing a row's color depending on the value ( TEXT ) of a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

In a cell, I have the choice of `YES` and `NO` for values. I would like to know how to change the background color for other cells in the same row depending on the value of the first without changing the values in the other cells.

How can I do this?

Comment: If Yes the row would be Green - IF NO, The row would be Red

Comment: It has been already answered, please check here [Change background color of the row or range if a particular cell value is equal to some text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355419/change-background-color-of-the-row-or-range-if-a-particular-cell-value-is-equal)

Answer (score 5):

No code required.

- Select cells C15 to N15
- click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format
- enter this formula

`=$M15="yes"`

- select a format, for example green fill and close all dialogs
- keep the cells selected and enter another rule with the formula

`=$M15="no"`

- select a format, for example a red fill and close all dialogs.

You can now copy the cells and use Paste special > Formats to copy the conditional formatting to other rows.

[image]

Comment: Teylyn --> You are great ! Thank you SO Much - It work and was pretty easy to do

Comment: @Martin, thanks for the feedback. If your question is answered, please mark the answer by clicking on the check mark, so others can see that there is a solution.